# Is it possible to modify pulse schedules in QASM?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices, qasm, openpulse

Is it possible to modify a pulse schedule of a circuit compiled using QASM? I know this is possible using OpenPulse, but it seems none of the IBM backends support OpenPulse. So is it possible to do this through QASM? [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03452) gives me the impression that I would only be able to modify the QASM command order, but not the actual pulse schedule. Is this correct?

Comment: I thought `ibmq_armonk` support openPulse, no? This is their 1 qubit machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean at the circuit schedule level, then yes the transpiler supports scheduling a circuit and resolving all timing by inserting appropriate delays on all qubits according to the selected scheduling policy.  See the transpiler option [scheduling_method here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html#qiskit-compiler-transpile). As KAJ226 notes, for more explicit control you may use the pulse level [Schedule](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.pulse.Schedule.html) representation which may be obtained as shown in this [tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/10_pulse_scheduler.html). However, only ibmq_armonk currently supports public pulse access.